# Appium Node.js Jasmine to test native applications

Tags: node.js, jasmine, appium, webdriver-io, appium-ios

I am trying to use Appium to test native iOS and Android applications.  I am currently trying to get it to work with a native iOS application using Appium, node.js, webdriver.io, jasmine.

I run Appium using Appium Desktop.  When I run npm test, it will launch a simulator window for the device specified in my capabilities section.

My wdio.conf.js file has the following:

```
exports.config = {

host: '127.0.0.1',

port: 4723,

path:  '/wd/hub',
```

.....

```
capabilities: [
    {
        automationName: "appium",
        address: '127.0.0.1',
        commandTimeout: '7200',
        sessionOverride: true,
        debugLogSpacing: true,
        platformVersion: '10.1',
        platformName: 'iOS',
        showIosLog: true,
        deviceName: 'iPhone 6s',
        nativeInstrumentsLib: true,
        isolateSimDevice: true,
        autoLaunch: true,
        app: '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../myapp.app'
    }
]
```

My test.js file has:

```
describe('test', function() {
    it('test', function () {
        console.log("HEREEEEE");
    }); 
});
```

If I use autoLaunch: true, then it will launch the simulator and the application, and output my console statement, then close the simulator.

**If I use autoLaunch:false, then what do I use to launch the application within my test case?**  I tried browser.launch() but it doesn't do anything and the test never runs (console statement never prints).

The appium log file has:
Failed to launch *myapp*: The operation couldn’t be completed. Application *myapp*" is unknown to FrontBoard.